# Regex: Match all string but capture groups between two symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, split

**Question:**

Given this string:

```
str = "this is<< just>> an example <<sentence>>"
```

How do you get the following array:

```
arr = ["this is", "<< just>>", " an example ", "<<sentence>>"]
```

**Attempts:**

I can split the string, however this removes the '<<' and '>>'.

```
str.split(/<<|>>/)
=> ["this is", " just", " an example ", "sentence"]
```

I can match the text blocks of text between and including '<<' and '>>', however this is missing the rest of the sentence.

```
str.match(/(<{2})(.*?>{2})/g)
=> ["<< just>>", "<<sentence>>"]
```

How do you capture the rest of the string as well as separate capture groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option - match `<<` up to and including `>>`, OR match characters up to the point where lookahead matches `<<` or the end of the string:

```js
const str = "this is<< just>> an example <<sentence>> foo";
const re = /<<.+?>>|.+?(?=<<|$)/g;
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by `<<...>>`

```js
const str = "this is<< just>> an example <<sentence>>"

const r = str.split(/(<<[^<>]+>>)/g)

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - add the matching groups to your split regex

```js
var str = "this is<< just>> an example <<sentence>>"
var result = str.split(/(<<|>>)/)
console.log(result);
```

or if you want the `<<>>` to be included, add them to your matching group

```
/(<<[^>]+>>)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by `<<...>>` and use `.filter(Boolean)` to filter out empty values.

```js
const str = "this is<< just>> an example <<sentence>>"

const r = str.split(/(<<[^<>]+>>)/g).filter(Boolean)

console.log(r)
```